# tikz: Right to left text within text along path

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, right-to-left, bidi

I have this example to write text along path using `decorations.text` library, and I want to insert arabic text starting  from right to left

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[rldocument]{bidi}

\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\tikzset{decoration={text along path,
text={Very very long text I need to show it from right to left}}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [decorate] (0,0)..controls +(45:4cm) and +(225:4cm)..(8,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My hope is to show the text along path from right to left in like manner

```
left to right from it show to need I text long very Very
```

Comment: the pgf manual has an entry `/pgf/decoration/text effects/reverse text` on page 602. It might help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it has been mentioned already, the `reverse text` effect described in the TikZ manual is what you are looking for.

However, you also want to **first** group the letters using the `group letters` effect, otherwise it reverses every single letter.

*Note that the order of both keys is important, in the example I provide below I wrote both orders to showcase the difference.*

**EDIT**: Forgot to slope the text to follow the path.  Using `characters={text along path}` you make sure that the text is sloped with the path.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\tikzset{
    decoration={
        text effects along path, 
        text={Very very long text I need to show it from right to left}
    }
} 

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Group letters, reverse text}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [
        decorate, 
        decoration= {
            text effects/.cd, 
                    group letters,
                    reverse text, 
                    characters={text along path}
        }] (0,0)..controls +(45:4cm) and +(225:4cm)..(8,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsection*{Reverse text, group letters}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [
        decorate, 
        decoration= {
            text effects/.cd, 
                    reverse text, 
                    group letters,
                    characters={text along path}
        }] (0,0)..controls +(45:4cm) and +(225:4cm)..(8,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Can you also demonstrate with actual RTL language characters?

Comment: There's a chance that the OP will want it right aligned along the path. You could add `text align=right` if this is desired.

Comment: @Percusse, can you provide a text you want to use? I couldn't use `xelatex` with the arabic fonts on the question, since I don't have those fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that's what I  need  `group letters` then `reverse text`.