# problem with persian words in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, xepersian, persian

I want to have a circular flow including persian words (employing xepersian package and xelatex compiler is necessary for persian language) using tikz picture, but latex makes characters of persian words separated. how I can fix it?

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\newcommand{\arcarrow}[8]% inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle, end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{#3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{#6}
\fill[#7] (\astart:\rin) arc (\astart:\aend:\rin) -- (\aend+\atip:\rmid) -- (\aend:\rout) arc (\aend:\astart:\rout) -- (\astart+\atip:\rmid) -- cycle;
\path[decoration={text along path, text={#8}, text align={align=center}, raise=-0.5ex},decorate] (\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill[even odd rule,lime!30] circle (3.8) circle (3.2);
 \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{0}{118}{5}{magenta,draw=red!50!black,very thick}{کاهش ارزش آورده}
 \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{120}{238}{5}{green,draw=red!50!black,very thick}{{کاهش ارزش آورده}}
 \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{240}{358}{5}{cyan,draw=red!50!black,very thick}{{کاهش ارزش آورده}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to compile your document but the `kpfonts` package is necessary and it is impossible for me to install it via `Texmaker` or via the `MikTeX`console.  "The required file `fonts\afm\public\kpfonts\jkplmne.afm` is missing.
It is a part of the following package: `kpfonts`
There's always that error:  "Unfortunately, the package kpfonts could not be installed"

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410820 seems relevant, but I’m not experienced enough with `tikz` to apply it to your example.

Comment: @AndréC Please download xb niloofar font from [here](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/xb-niloofar) then it should work

Comment: Yes, by installing these fonts on windows, I can compile. I don't know Persian, so I don't see what the problem is in writing words. Can you add screenshots to your question that visually explain the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will solve the problem (see this [link](http://qa.parsilatex.com/30936/%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1-tikz-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%85-%D9%85%D8%AD%DB%8C%D8%B7-%D8%AF%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%A7%DB%8C)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\newcommand{\arcarrow}[8]% inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle,                 end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{#3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{#6}
    \fill[#7] (\astart:\rin) arc (\astart:\aend:\rin) -- (\aend+\atip:\rmid) --     (\aend:\rout) arc (\aend:\astart:\rout) -- (\astart+\atip:\rmid) -- cycle;
    \path[decoration={text effects along path, text align=center,
        text={#8}, 
        text effects/.cd, 
        group letters,
        reverse text, 
        characters={text along path,},
        text effects={align=center},
    },
    decorate] (\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[even odd rule,lime!30] circle (3.8) circle (3.2);
     \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{0}{118}{5}{magenta,draw=red!50!black,very thick}{کاهش ارزش     آورده}
     \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{120}{238}{5}{green,draw=red!50!black,very thick}{کاهش ارزش آورده}
     \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{240}{358}{5}{cyan,draw=red!50!black,very thick}{کاهش ارزش آورده}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```