# Making a logo with Arabic text

Tags: arabic, logos

I am trying to use this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75652/134574
with Arabic letters:

I can replace the MTG in the center of the logo (replaced by my command `\ism` in the preamble with arabic letters), but I can't do it around the circle (I put my attempt in a comment). Here is my working modification:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{fontspec,amssymb}
\setmainfont{OptimusPrinceps}
\definecolor{byublue}{RGB}{0 34 85}
\newfontfamily\bolderfont{OptimusPrincepsSemiBold}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}


\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{DecoType Thuluth II}
%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\newcommand{\ism}{\textarabic{بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw[color=gray,fill=byublue] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
\draw[color=gray,fill=white] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);
\end{scope}
%\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (2.5cm) node[scale=1.5] (m) 
%{\Huge\bolderfont MTG};
\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (2.5cm) node[scale=1.5] (m) 
{\large\bolderfont \ism};



\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (3.6cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1ex,text along path, 
reverse path,text align=center, text={|\huge\color{white}|Quick Latin 
Motto Erratum Et Al.}}}] (-30:3.05cm) arc (-30:210:3.05cm);
\node[white,rotate=-60] at (210:3.05cm) {$\blacklozenge$};
\node[white,rotate=60] at (330:3.05cm) {$\blacklozenge$};

\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1ex,text along path, text 
align=center, text={|\huge\color{white}|St. John's College }}}] 
(210:3.05cm) arc (210:330:3.05cm);

 %%%%%%%%\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1ex,text along 
 %%%path, text align=center, text={|\huge\color{white}| \ism }}}] 
 %%(210:3.05cm) arc (210:330:3.05cm);


 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

The fonts I am using can be found here: [thuluth fonts](https://arbfonts.com/arabic_fonts/font-weights-DecoType-Thuluth-II).

Here's the output pdf I have:

[image: logo Arabic]

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410820/54817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry if the text doesn't make any sense, but) here you go:

> [image]

Your code didn't work because you can't use a macro (`\ism`) there, only plain text because the command used to make the text circular does not expand macros. And you also have to explicitly tell it to use `\arabicfont` otherwise it will not find the glyphs it needs.

```latex
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{fontspec,amssymb}
\setmainfont{OptimusPrinceps}
\definecolor{byublue}{RGB}{0 34 85}
\newfontfamily\bolderfont{OptimusPrincepsSemiBold}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}


\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{DecoType Thuluth II}
%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\newcommand{\ism}{\textarabic{بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw[color=gray,fill=byublue] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
\draw[color=gray,fill=white] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);
\end{scope}
%\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (2.5cm) node[scale=1.5] (m) 
%{\Huge\bolderfont MTG};
\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (2.5cm) node[scale=1.5] (m) 
{\large\bolderfont \ism};

\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (3.6cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-0.5ex,text along path, 
reverse path,text align=center, text={|\LARGE\color{white}\arabicfont|بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم بسم الله الرحم
}}}] (-20:3.05cm) arc (-20:200:3.05cm);
\node[white,rotate=-60] at (200:3.05cm) {$\blacklozenge$};
\node[white,rotate=60] at  (-20:3.05cm) {$\blacklozenge$};

\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-0.5ex,text along 
path, text align=center, text={|\LARGE\color{white}\arabicfont|بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم
}}}]
(200:3.05cm) arc (200:340:3.05cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much .. i ll try to continue

Comment: @sajid You are welcome. If you have any problems along the way , you are welcome to [ask a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Also, to show future readers that the problem is solved you can mark the answer as "accepted" (see: [how to accept an answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1853/134574)).

Comment: this is nice from you .. thanks for your time : )