# Tikz sweeps location of text inside node with Hebrew

Tags: tikz-pgf, hebrew, right-to-left

For some reason the text of the second node is not printed inside the box of the node, but on the complete opposite side of the tikzpicture.

Any idea on how to fix it?

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}

\usepackage[english,hebrew,bidi=basic,provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!33}, show background rectangle]

\node [draw,text width=0.75\textwidth, align=left, outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt](n1) {%
לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט.
};

\node [draw,below = 0pt of n1.south east,anchor=north east,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt](n2) {%
שלום עולם};
\filldraw (n2) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

(The MWE is with beamer but happens with article and book as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the package option `layout=graphics`, that is:

```
\usepackage[english,hebrew,bidi=basic,layout=graphics,provide=*]{babel}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, this is nice to know! Up to now, I always changed the language to English (or any other LTR language) for the Ti*k*Z environment and only in the nodes set the language back to the RTL language. This makes things much easier!

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes, [I remember](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663013/) :)

Comment: Mixing RTL and LTR stuff is far from trivial. This options mostly works, but it may fail in some cases. Just report any issue you find and I’ll fix it (more precisely, I’ll do my best to fix it).

Comment: @JavierBezos That's right, as, for example, in the answer I wrote.

Answer (score -1):

Note that inserting a `\noindent` before the `tikzpicture` environment results in the problem to stay, regardless of the `layout=graphics` option.

Same with inserting text before the environment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%% same preamble as in Javier Bezos' answer
\begin{document}
אבג% so there is no \par command before the tikzpicture
\begin{tikzpicture}
〈same code〉
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I’ll have a look at it, but please don’t report bugs as an answer. Either ask for help or report the bug as explained in the manual or in the readme (I wonder if the downvote is for this reason, or perhaps because it’s not a MWE, but I would suggest to the downvoter a more constructive approach with a comment about the reason).  I’ve opened an issue: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/227