# TikZ nodes becoming misaligned with their labels when the document's language is Hebrew

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, hebrew, tabularray, adjustbox

The following code produces the expected output seen below. (I use Overleaf with the 2022 LuaLaTeX engine.)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[bidi=basic,provide=*,english,hebrew,layout=graphics]{babel}
%\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSerif}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\NewDocumentCommand{\points}{}{%
\draw (0,0) node [circle,fill=red,label={[label distance=.5cm]-90:$r$}] (r1) {}
      (1,0) node [circle,fill=red,label={[label distance=.5cm]-90:$r'$}] (r2) {}
      (2,0) node [circle,fill=blue,label={[label distance=.5cm]-90:$b'$}] (b1) {}
      (3,0) node [circle,fill=blue,label={[label distance=.5cm]-90:$b$}] (b2) {};
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\colsinnersep}{}{2cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tblr}{cells={halign=c,valign=m},row{1}={belowsep={.5cm}},column{1}={rightsep={\colsinnersep}},column{2}={leftsep={\colsinnersep}}}
Before
&
After
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
\points;
\draw[very thick] (r1) |- ($(b1)+(0,.5)$) -- (b1);
\draw[very thick] (r2) |- ($(b2)+(0,-.5)$) -- (b2);
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
\points;
\draw[very thick] (r1) |- ($(b2)+(0,.5)$) -- (b2);
\draw[very thick] (r2) |- ($(b1)+(0,-.5)$) -- (b1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tblr}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: Document's language is English by default]

However, when the two commented-out lines are uncommented thus making the document's main language Hebrew, the following incorrect output is produced.

[image: The document's main language is Hebrew]

Note that the problem is not that table's original left and right columns have switched places. This is correct behavior, since Hebrew is a right-to-left language. The problem is that the pictures are no longer centered in the columns, and the colored nodes are not aligned with their labels. Another problem is that the nodes' labels are written from right to left.

Why has this happened? How can it be fixed?

Comment: It looks like it works with an up to date version of `babel`. just copy the relevant files to your project. I think `babel.sty`, `luababel.def` and `babel-bidi-basic.lua` should be enough for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel had a bug with "inline" `tikz` pictures. See [this page](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/211) and [Tikz sweeps location of text inside node with Hebrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679730/tikz-sweeps-location-of-text-inside-node-with-hebrew/679828#679828).

Adding the following line after `\usepackage{tikz}` should solve this (credit to Salim Bou):

```
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/begin}{\bbl@pictsetdir\tw@}
        \bbl@add\tikz@atbegin@node{\bbl@pictresetdir}
        \bbl@sreplace\tikz{\begingroup}{\begingroup\bbl@pictsetdir\tw@}
\makeatother
```

But working with an up to date version of `babel` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `\selectlanguage{english}` in each of the TikZ pictures' cells just before the `begin{tikzpicture}` commands. The result is:

[image: Selecting English as the language in each of the TikZ pictures' cells]