# witharrows package reverses text in RTL language?

Tags: polyglossia, right-to-left, witharrows

I do my homework in Latex, and I recently learned about the `witharrows` package which allows me to draw arrows between lines explaining what I did there. I find this very helpful for my homework assignments. However, there is a weird problem when I try to use the package. I do my homework in our native language, Hebrew, an RTL language. I use the `polyglossia` and `fontspec` packages to configure the language settings and fonts of the document.

When I tried to use the `witharrows` package with this simple example:

```
דוגמה לחישוב:
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
A &= (a + b)^2 \Arrow{נפתח את הסוגריים בביטוי} \\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{DispWithArrows*}
```

I got this output:
[image]

As you can see, the text next to the arrow is reversed. It looks like it's trying to write it in an LTR setting for some reason. After reading [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662156/right-to-left-text-in-tikz-picture),
I tried to use the option `font=\selectlanguage{hebrew}` like so:

```
\tikzset{
    WithArrows/arrow/.append style = {
        font = \selectlanguage{hebrew},
    }
}
```

However, it didn't work. I got the same output. Note that I did it in `tikzset` so it applies to all arrows, but doing it inside the arrow itself:
`\Arrow[tikz={font={\selectlanguage{hebrew}}}]{נפתח את הסוגריים בביטוי}` doesn't work either.

I did some more experiments and I found something very weird: If I add another setting to the font such as changing the color:

```
\tikzset{
    WithArrows/arrow/.append style = {
        color=blue,
        font = \selectlanguage{hebrew},
    }
}
```

It suddenly works and renders correctly from right to left, and that's extremely weird. Another solution that I found to work is using `\texthebrew`:

```
דוגמה לחישוב:
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
A &= (a + b)^2 \Arrow{\texthebrew{נפתח את הסוגריים בביטוי}} \\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{DispWithArrows*}
```

which also renders correctly. The first solution is just weird and I'd like to know why adding the `color` option suddenly fixes it (of course I can use `color=black` so the color doesn't change but this feels like a dirty hack and not a real solution), and while the second solution makes sense, I don't want to always have to surround the text in my arrows with a `\texthebrew` command and I couldn't find a way to apply it globally.

Does anyone know how I can fix these issues and get Hebrew text to render correctly in arrows?

Full example code (Note I use the font [Assistant](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Assistant)):

```
% !TeX spellcheck = he_HE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{witharrows}

% Font and language settings
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[
    Script=Hebrew,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3},
]{Assistant}

\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setsansfont{Assistant}
\setmonofont{Assistant}

\WithArrowsOptions{displaystyle}
\tikzset{
    WithArrows/arrow/.append style = {
        font = \selectlanguage{hebrew},
    }
}

\begin{document}
דוגמה לחישוב:
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
A &= (a + b)^2 \Arrow{נפתח את הסוגריים בביטוי} \\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/0x40DQR) correct?

Comment: Do you absolutely need the `no-math` option for `fontspec`? Because if not you could drop `\usepackage{fontspec}` as it is already loaded by `polyglossia`. Your MWE compiles without `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`.

Comment: If the image I have attached is correct, then I am guessing the culprit is the compiler (XeLaTeX). With up-to-date LaTeX installation and LuaLaTeX I was able to produce that output with the _exact_ same code.

Comment: @Niranjan Yes, the picture you posted is correct. I am quite sure I need the `no-math` option. It fixed a different issue I had a month ago. I don't even remember what it was.

Comment: You can just define a new command to insert your RTL text like this `\def\ArrowRL#1{\Arrow{\texthebrew{#1}}}`  then `\ArrowRL{נפתח את הסוגריים בביטוי}`

Comment: @ShaiAvr Ah, okay. If the image is correct and you don't want to change a lot of things, just shift to LuaLaTeX. That would be the easiest. There are other advantages of LuaLaTeX too.

Comment: @Niranjan Switching to LuaLatex indeed solved this issue. However, a new issue appeared: For a weird reason, `align*` environments are put on the right side of the page instead of the center as it's supposed to be. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 7):

That problem is not specific to `witharrows`. It's a problem of the PGF/Tikz nodes (in conjunction with `polyglossia` and `xelatex`).

I think that the best solution is to put a command `\tikzset{text=.}`  in the preamble of the document ("." will be the current color at the time of creation of the Tikz node).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{witharrows}

% Font and language settings
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[
    Script=Hebrew,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3},
]{Assistant}

\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setsansfont{Assistant}
\setmonofont{Assistant}


\tikzset{text=.}  % "." is the current color

\WithArrowsOptions{displaystyle,tikz={font=}}

\begin{document}


דוגמה לחישוב:
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
A &= (a + b)^2 \Arrow{נפתח את הסוגריים בביטוי} \\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

I think that the origin of the problem is that PGF uses `\hbox` to construct the boxes containing the contents of its nodes (at least when `text width` is not used). That command `\hbox`, which is a primitive of TeX, is not ''color-safe'' (whereas the commands of constructions of boxes of LaTeX, such as `\mbox` are all ''color-safe''). With a box which is not ``color-safe'', the commands to pop the color from the stack are in fact after the box (inserted with a `\aftergroup`) and may have bad consequences.

By putting `\tikzset{text=.}` in the preamble, instructions to put color are inserted at each PGF node, and the protection added (to avoid color links) has probably an action to prevent also problems with RTL mode (I assume the command `\hbox` is not ''RTL-safe'').

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works without any hacks with `lualatex`. I'd appreciate it if you could explain this.

Comment: The gestion of the fonts is not the same in `lualatex` and in `xelatex`. Both supports OpenType fonts but with different technics.